# Can an android app copy contacts with read contact permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, contacts

So there's an app that asks permission to read contacts. It's needs this access to check phone numbers against it's own member list. No problem with that.

This works by an option "add from contacts" where you pick a contact and the app checks whether that contact is a member by the phone number and reports accordingly in a pop up. Is or isn't a member.

Someone used an android proxy and captured the app traffic and discovered the app was posting the entire contacts list with ALL fields even email and postal addresses to it's servers.

My question is does allowing the app to read contacts by extension allow it to copy contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely, how an app works is that there's a database of contacts on the phone, when you give it the permission to read contacts, basically you give it access to the database, and it can without anything to stop it, do whatever it wants with it.